# What does "hold on to your hair" mean?

Tags: phrases

What does this phrase mean?

> hold on to your hair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Hold on to your hat" and "keep your hair on" are common English phrases that mean "ready yourself for a rough / exciting experience" and "don't get too excited" respectively. The first is obvious enough, the second is a reference to wigs (more fashionable in previous times, and could come off when the wearer was agitated). Never heard of "hold on to your hair", but it sounds like a conflation of the two.

Google NGram for the three phrases [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hold+on+to+your+hair%2Chold+on+to+your+hat%2C+keep+your+hair+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chold%20on%20to%20your%20hat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckeep%20your%20hair%20on%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I hadn't previously known that 'keep your hair on' referred to wigs. It used to be thought that excessive stress and worry made men go bald. I always thought it was connected to that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure that this is not the sense that the OP is asking about, but: "holding your hair" is a somewhat common phrase in popular culture (certainly American, and some British - think of *Bridget Jones' Diary*, for example).

When a group of friends or coworkers go out to a bar, it is unfortunately rather common for one or more of them to drink until they vomit.  A true friend is said to be one who will **hold your hair** out of the way, so that it doesn't either trail in the toilet or get splashed with vomitus.

Taken literally, it only applies to drinkers with very long hair - usually, but not always, young women - but it's also used as a figure of speech when one friend is suggesting some risky or unwise behavior:  "My roommate and I are going out on the town tonight.  Why don't you come along and hold my hair?"